# DFS mount on Ubuntu with failover capabilities

Tags: 14.04, fstab, cifs, failover

I need some help here. I am trying to mount cifs (Windows DFS, which is a cluster of two exactly identical machines) to my ubuntu 16.04.01.

I have good success with the mount itself, what I am doing is a permanent mount adding the following in the fstab:

```
//servername/sharename /mnt/filestore cifs credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

which is working and I have no worries mounting this. The issue comes up when I am testing the fail over between the two servers. If I kill the machine with the active session between the Linux and my DFS share, the Ubuntu starts trying to restore the same session instead connecting to the other Windows server.

**Example:**

If ubuntu is 10.10.10.10, fileserver1 is 10.10.10.11 and fileserver2 is 10.10.10.12. Ubuntu has a running session with fileserver1, which I kill, now Ubuntu (10.10.10.10) is trying to restore the session with fileserver1 (10.10.10.11), instead connecting to fileserver2 (10.10.10.12).

Any help/advice is appreciated.